# How to delete files when their amount reaches >N number of files?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a game server. It auto-gets players’ screenshots and stores at  `/home/gameserver/serverfiles/screenshots`.

I want to delete old screenshots when it reaches 1000. I mean if it’s 1000 screenshots, when a new screenshot comes, it auto-deletes the 1000th screenshot.

How can I do that, which scripts can I use? Can anyone give suggestion or codes?

Note: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and my game server user hasn't sudo access.

I want to maintain my screenshot folder to hold max 1000 images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming format to be any of the `jpg, jpeg and png` you can write a short script which counts and deletes all files if the count is `>=1000`. A short working example would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=`ls -l *.{jpg,jpeg,png} | wc -l`

if [ $count -gt 1000 ]
then 
    echo "Deleting old 1000 image files"
    for i in $(ls -lt *.{jpg,jpeg,png} | head -n 1000)
    do
        rm $i
    done
fi
```

You can then add this script to `crontab` to execute it every 10 minutes(for example).
Type `crontab -e` to edit it.

Comment: Yes you're right I will edit the script for automated deletion of only the first 1000 files when sorted datewise

Comment: @Melebius I have made the edits

Comment: Made the change

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts. If you replace `head -n 1000` with `tail -n -1000` it will output the oldest files where there are more than 1000 files (so if you have 1007 files, it will report the 7 oldest files which you can then delete. Also watch out for file names with a space in them (may not be relevant on your system), but you may want to quote (`"`) $i in the rm line and the $( ...) section